# Raspbian ignores /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: raspbian, networking

I would like to connect my pc and my raspbian through a network without internet output.

I have a router with the **dhcp** disabled, and I connect to this router my raspberry pi 2 and my pc. The pc picks good the interfaces configuration, but raspberry pi is doing weird things.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:91:1d:60  
          inet addr:169.254.252.195  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a05c:8c24:cad8:6a3f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2280 (2.2 KiB)  TX bytes:50845 (49.6 KiB)
```

This is the configuration of the interface eth0. I have this in my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.3.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The ip of the router is `192.168.3.1`, and netmask is `255.255.255.0`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the behavior any different if you replace `allow-hotplug` with `auto`?  I don't know if the kernel delivers a hotplug event for the ethernet interface...

Comment: Possibly related http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37471/34558

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Warning! For this to work properly `dhcpcd` needs to be disabled. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Don't be lazy. Configure it completely.

```
auto eth0                      #add this line
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.3.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.3.1
        network 192.168.3.0
        broadcast 192.168.3.255
```

Comment: Maybe he's not lazy... My raspberry images, tripi and raspbian so far, just didn't had that line. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Saiyine That line is part of the "Configure it completely" statement :)

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you are running a DHCP client.  This attempts to get an IP address for your network interface, gateway address and nameservers for your DHCP server.  This is over-riding what you have configured in your `/etc/network/interfaces` definition.  The solution is to edit the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file and add static definitions for your named interface in there.  See the man page for dhcpcd.conf for details and/or google for further examples of folks having configured Raspbian and DHCP client.  For example:

http://sizious.com/2015/08/28/setting-a-static-ip-on-raspberry-pi-on-raspbian-20150505/

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian does not "ignore" `/etc/network/interfaces` but the file you listed WILL NOT set a static address, `dhcpcd` will still try to allocate an address.

`addr:169.254.252.195` is a link-local address so for some reason this has not happened.

See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for a tutorial on how to correctly configure networking.

Alternatively you can disable `dhcpcd`.